# localstorage only stores one object instead of adding concatenating them

Tags: javascript, local-storage

The idea of the below code is to add some product details to a localstorage variable everytime someone visits a product page with the goal to remember the last visited products. However, the variable only stores one product instead of adding them with "|" separators after each other. Hope someone can help out. The code seems legit.

Regards

```
    events.domReady( function() {
      var objLookedAt = {
        'name' : document.getElementById('name').innerHTML.trim(),
        'type' : document.getElementById('type').innerText.trim(),
        'uri' : location.href,
        'imgUri' : document.getElementById('productImg').src,
        'price' : document.querySelectorAll('#prodPrice > span')[0].innerHTML.trim(),
        'quantity' : document.querySelectorAll('#prodPrice > span')[1].innerHTML.trim()
      },
      cRead = window.localStorage.getItem('lvp'),
      stringToSave = JSON.stringify( objLookedAt ),
      obj, ind, currSave = [], seen = false;

      if(cRead) {
        currSave = cRead.split('|');
        for(var i = 0; i < currSave.length; i++) {
          obj = JSON.parse(currSave[i]);
          if(objLookedAt.name === obj.name) {
            seen = true;
            ind = i;
          }
        }
      }
      if( seen ) {
        currSave.splice(ind, 1);
      }
      currSave.reverse().push(stringToSave);
      var cRev = currSave.reverse();
      window.localStorage.setItem('lvp', cRev.slice(0, 4).join('|'));
    });
```

Comment: I would set an array of objects in `localStorage` instead of separating them by `|` and then each time someone visits your website you could perform a check whether localStorage array contains already an object with the same properties as the new one, which seems to be what you're trying to achieve. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's true, but then I have to rewrite everything. I started from a basic code of someone else, that's why I continued the same road.

Comment: so, the code you posted is already in production? Or is this your attempt to extend the current code. I suppose the current code only saves one item and you want to extend it to the last 4, am I right?

Comment: besides the formatting-issues, you can reduce most of your code to this `var cRev = [ objLookedAt ].concat( cRead? cRead.split("|").map(JSON.parse).filter(function(obj){ return obj.name !== objLookedAt.name }).slice(0, 3): [] );`

Comment: That's correct Thomas! I want to extend it to 4. I want to extend the code. Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: So for backward-compatibility, you only have to handle wether `lvp` contains the JSON of a single item or an Array of items. Only this one distinction !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, this should do the job, 
and Array.concat() manages Arrays and single values for you.

```
events.domReady( function() {
    var objLookedAt = {
        'name' : document.getElementById('name').innerHTML.trim(),
        'type' : document.getElementById('type').innerText.trim(),
        'uri' : location.href,
        'imgUri' : document.getElementById('productImg').src,
        'price' : document.querySelectorAll('#prodPrice > span')[0].innerHTML.trim(),
        'quantity' : document.querySelectorAll('#prodPrice > span')[1].innerHTML.trim()
    };

    var lvp = window.localStorage.getItem('lvp');
    var cRev = [ objLookedAt ].concat(
            //JSON.parse( lvp || "[]" )     //this should actually be fine,
            tryToParseAsJson( lvp ) || []   //but safety first
        )
        .filter(function(obj){ 
            return obj === objLookedAt || obj.name !== objLookedAt.name 
        })
        .slice(0, 4);

    window.localStorage.setItem('lvp', JSON.stringify( cRev ));
});

//may be handy in different places
function tryToParseAsJson(str){
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    }catch(err){}
}
```

**Edit:** If you have multiple places that have to access the localStorage, build an abstraction, and leave the serialization/deserialization-task to this abstraction.

```
//utils
var AP = Array.prototype;
function tryToParseAsJson(str){
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    }catch(err){}
}

//an abstraction for the local storage.
//change all code to use this abstraction, leave all the serialization to this module
var store = {
    //you might want to extend that, so that this module does everything involving the localStore
    lvp: {
        //always returns an Array, although it may be empty
        get(){
            return AP.concat( tryToParseAsJson( window.localStorage.getItem('lvp') ) || AP );
        },

        //expects an Array of objects, 
        //also works if you only pass one item (through the parsing-process)
        set(arr){
            window.localStorage.setItem('lvp', 
                arr == null || typeof arr !== "object"? "": JSON.stringify( arr )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And your code only utilizes this module

```
events.domReady(function() {
    var objLookedAt = {
        'name' : document.getElementById('name').innerHTML.trim(),
        'type' : document.getElementById('type').innerText.trim(),
        'uri' : location.href,
        'imgUri' : document.getElementById('productImg').src,
        'price' : document.querySelectorAll('#prodPrice > span')[0].innerHTML.trim(),
        'quantity' : document.querySelectorAll('#prodPrice > span')[1].innerHTML.trim()
    };

    function isNotObjLookedAt(o){
        return o.name !== objLookedAt.name 
    }

    store.lvp.set( [ objLookedAt ].concat( store.lvp.get().filter( isNotObjLookedAt ).slice(0,3) ) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Just checked it and when I do window.localStorage.getItem('lvp'); in the console on the page where the js is fired, I get this result: "[object Object]"

Comment: this sounds like you've not stringified the value before passing it to localStorage.setItem(). I've just tested the code by mocking objLookedAt and it works perfectly.

Comment: I don't really know how, I copied your full code, but it just returns object. Does this mean that I need to change the code that follows on the one you adjusted as well, to get the data out of the localstorage? 

`var lsString = window.localStorage.getItem('lvp'),
    lsArray = lsString.split('|');`

Comment: I'm not sure wether I understand you right. You have some different code that accesses/utilizes lvp as well, and you ask wether you have to modify this code as well? Sure, this code handled one Object, now it may get an Array of items.

Comment: Hi Thomas, one more thing. I have used your code, but I was wondering if you could help me and let me know how I can display the values of the stored objects in the console? That would be great, thanks!

Comment: I can't get anything out but [object object] :(

Comment: Okay no worries, it was an issue in my browser, sorry mate! Thanks for all the help, you're the best!